# A good management of Java code

Tags: java, beginner, memory-management

I'm a beginner in JEE development.  I have just finished a web application that I'm going to deploy in a server.

It's a new level for me; it's not just a simple application that I can run for 10 min, etc.

My question is for the quality of code.  Of course we all know that a piece of code that works does not mean it's correct.  In my managed beans, I use `@postConstruct`, for example:

```
@PostConstruct
public void post() {
    listChaletss = chaletService.getAllChalet();

    for (Chalet it : listChaletss) {

        if (it.getType().equals("permanent")) {

            listChaletp.add(it);
        }
    }
    allPeriodes = periodeService.getAllPeriodes();
    // System.out.println("size periode" + allPeriodes.size());
    for (Chalet order : listChaletss) {
        order.setEditable(false);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if someone can determine if we can face any memory problems using this application.  Some piece of code and any help from some Java experts will be welcomed.

Comment: you are iterating listChaletss two times. This could be expensive. When you have this type situation, try to manage your structure in one iteration.

Comment: Why are you worried about memory problems in this particular code sample (when i overlook the loop redundancy)? Did you run it through some analysis or does it sometimes causes problems/exceptions/etc?

Answer (score 4):

Your variables `listChaletss`, `listChaletp`, and `allPeriodes` appear to be instance variables.  We can't tell whether you're leaking memory without further context — what is the expected lifetime of this object?  If this object only has a brief existence, then you probably don't have to worry about how it uses memory.  On the other hand, if it's a long-lived object, you have to be careful.

There is cause for concern, though.  You store the result of `.getAllChalet()` in instance variable `listChaletss`.  Why an instance variable?  Is `listChaletss` acting as some kind of cache?  If so, then the code would likely be:

```
public void post() {
    if (null == listChaletss) {
        listChaletss = chaletService.getAllChalet();
    }
    ...
}
```

… or better yet:

```
private Chalet[] getChalets() {
    if (null == listChaletss) {
        listChaletss = chaletService.getAllChalet();
    }
    return listChaletss;
}

public void post() {
    for (Chalet it : getChalets()) {
        ...
}
```

… or better yet, use a `WeakReference`.

On the other hand, if `listChaletss` is *not* meant to be a cache, then you should just make it a local variable so that you don't hang on to the result.  Unintentionally keeping a reference to the result leads to a "lingering" memory leak: you waste memory storing `listChaletss`, but you recover that memory the next time you call `.post()`, only to waste it again.

Similar considerations apply to your other two instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

A possible memory concern that I can think of is this line:

```
listChaletp.add(it);
```

If you're never **removing** elements from that list (which is hard for me to know since I only see a portion of your code), then sooner or later **that list will get out of control** (have too many useless elements) which will **eat up your memory**.

Besides this, the only possible concerns is your `periodeService.getAllPeriodes()` and `chaletService.getAllChalet()` but if those do what it sounds like they do (simply return a list without any computation or modifications of those lists) then you don't need to worry about those methods.